# Django - ImportError: No module named views

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am developing an application in python 2.7 and using Django, when I run it on my local machine (windows 7) it runs well without any error, but when I try to run it in a virtual machine with ubuntu server where it also used to work well, it crashes with the 
[following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNxd.png)

This is my project working tree:

```
- MYSITE
    * BMM
         ·admin.py
         ·apps.py
         ·models.py
         ·pdf_utils.py
         ·urls.py
         ·views.py
     *Mysite
         ·settings.py
         ·urls.py
         ·wsgi.py
```

This is the **app\urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView

from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
#   url(r'^$', views.pdf, name='pdf'),
#   url(r'^$', views.ganttChart, name='ganttChart'),
    url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='billReport.html',filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),
    url(r'^report/$', views.report, name='report'),
]
```

And this is the **mysite/urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
#from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'',include('bmm.urls')),
    url(r'^ganttchart/', include('bmm.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='billReport.html', filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),    
]
```

Any help about how to solve this would be really appreciated

Comment: which django version you are using ?

Comment: just checked and I am using 1.9.1 in the Ubuntu Server machine and 1.9.2 in the W7 machine, could this be the problem?

Comment: It would help if you could include the full stack trace

Comment: is there any application called wkhtmltopdf in your site?

Comment: Checkout if wkhtmltopdf is correctly installed on your virtual machine. And if you don't have another module named wkhtmltopdf in your Python path that may take precedence.

Comment: Are you using this (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.1) package? If not provide link for that package.

Comment: as @MHassan was saying if you are using that wkhtmltopdf package, then check properly if that is installed properly (or) atleast check if it is part of your PYTHONPATH (or) virtualenv

If it is application in your site itself, can you please list the directory structure of that application in your site.

Comment: @rpc 'wkhtmltopdf` is it in you'r INSTALLED_APPS setting ?

Comment: Just solved it with the help of all your answers, the problem was that I had the normal wkhtmltopdf library installed instead of the specific wkhtmltopdf for Django version, thanks everyone who wasted his time answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNxd.png) you are getting is self-explanatory.

It seems you have installed wrong package. you have installed [wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.1) package which has no module named "view". That's why you are getting [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNxd.png): "No module named views"

The correct package is [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wkhtmltopdf), which has module named "view".

Uninstall [wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.1)  and install [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wkhtmltopdf).
You can find installation and setup instruction for django-wkhtmltopdf [here](http://django-wkhtmltopdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
1.pip uninstall wkhtmltopdf
2.pip install django-wkhtmltopdf
```

Don't forget to put `wkhtmltopdf` in `INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'wkhtmltopdf',
    # ...
)
```

Comment: As I explained above I already solved this issue, but I will accept this answer because it could help other people who face the same problem